# Android's MediaPlayer prepareAsync() timeout?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I am using `MediaPlayer`'s `prepareAsync()` function.

My code looks like:

```
try {
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream_url);
  mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

The issue is that sometimes `stream_url` is playing music, and sometimes `stream_url` is not playing music.  How can I notify the user if `stream_url` is not playing music?  Is there a timeout of some sort or an error I can catch?  Nothing is currently being thrown, it just calls asycn then does nothing if there is no stream.

Comment: Why don't you use mp.isPlaying() ?

Comment: it looks to me it attempts to reconnect forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look to documentation there are son available setter for listener and there is a setter that allows you to check error on async operation.

```
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener
```

*Interface definition of a callback to be invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation (other errors will throw exceptions at method call time).*